# Why does numpy.allclose use non-symmetrical comparison?

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

The [numpy.allclose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) is declared as `numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, ...)`, and implements a non-symmetrical comparison using:

```
absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
```

The result of the non-symmetrical comparison is that `allclose(a, b)` might be different from `allclose(b, a)` in some rare cases, thus making `allclose` non [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property), which is a surprising property for a comparison operator.

What is the reason for having a non-symmetrical comparison?

Comment: From [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html#numpy.isclose) (which is used by `allclose`) -- "Unlike the built-in [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/math.html#math.isclose), the above equation is not symmetric in `a` and `b` – it assumes `b` is the reference value – so that `isclose(a, b)` might be different from `isclose(b, a)`." -- `isclose` is already lacking the transitive property mathematically required by an equality relation so it's never going to be rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment, `math.isclose` uses `abs(a-b) <= max(rel_tol * max(abs(a), abs(b)), abs_tol)` which is commutative, but at the cost of an additional operation (which could be costly for numpy arrays which need to be stacked in order to find the maximum). It isn't hard to implement your own if you really require this property:

```
def isclose_comm(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
   ab = np.stack((a, b))
   return np.abs(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * ab.max(axis=0))

x = np.random.random(5)

x
Out[94]: array([0.36007049, 0.86934972, 0.05827216, 0.60794612, 0.24539454])

y = x + np.random.random(5)/1e6

y
Out[96]: array([0.36007072, 0.86934976, 0.05827312, 0.6079464 , 0.24539492])

np.isclose(x, y)
Out[97]: array([ True,  True,  False,  True,  True])

isclose_comm(x, y)
Out[98]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True])

z = np.zeros(5)

isclose_comm(x, z)
Out[100]: array([False, False, False, False, False])
```

`allclose` equivelent:

```
def allclose_comm(a, b, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-8):
    return isclose_comm(a, b, rtol, atol).all()
```

Comment: So from this it sounds like the reason is to speed up computation.  Relevant point about the `allclose` not having [transitive relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) anyway.